# Why Network status calculate too much?

Tags: windows, networking

In Network status window in control panel in network and internet  when i look at it doesn't show the proper size of download for example i transfer a 10 mb file and there will show 11 MB ,
Why?

Answer (score 2):

Probably network overhead and chatter.

Your 10 MB file isn't transferred as a single transaction, it is broken up into packets whose maximum size is limited by your LAN technology and which may be relatively small, those packets need to carry information about where they are going, where they came from, what priority they have, how many hops they have travelled so far and so on. They may arrive ou of order and so need to carry information that allows their payload to be reassembled in the right order.

Packets therefore carry more than just data. There are headers and checksums at multiple levels. There are packets that do related work (DNS lookups, ARP requests), there can be retransmits of lost packets, there can be encryption, tunelling and many other overheads.

Some systems, particularly those from Microsoft, spend a lot of time broadcasting things, advertising services, discovering services and trying to coordinate and negotiate roles in the local network. You need to be careful not to include this background chatter (more like a dull roar) in your measurements.

Download wireshark and use it - you'll find it quite enlightening.

Comment: There is a nice explanation at [TCP Over IP Bandwidth Overhead](http://packetpushers.net/tcp-over-ip-bandwidth-overhead/)

Comment: This will happen for all monitoring services  i mean in all monitoring it might calculate 10 Mb instead of 11 Mb?
for example does softwares in ISP calculate like this?
i ask these question because i want to develop a software.

Comment: @Armin. ISPs are interested in bandwidth utilisation. They don't care about payload. They would measure the larger quantity as that is a better representation of how much of their resources are being consumed. Just like when you drive a truck across a toll bridge they generally charge by the size or gross-weight of vehicle, not of the driver and load.

Comment: Now i'm developing a  monitoring software, for example when i download 10 MB file it shows 11 MB , does my program show corrected ? there is no problem with it?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937/why-must-we-avoid-discussions-in-comments